# How to link two existing items (many-to-many) via the OData HTTP protocol?

Tags: entity-framework, many-to-many, odata, wcf-data-services

I'm working with an EF data model which is exposed through an OData service endpoint. It has Person and Group entities which are connected through a many-to-many relationship.

[image: my data model]

I would like to add a link from an existing Person with an existing Group through OData, but I have been unable to figure out how. The OData protocol as specified [here (link to odata.org)](http://www.odata.org/media/6655/%5Bmc-apdsu%5D%5B1%5D.htm#_Toc246716600) seems to specify that I need to do the following HTTP request to link Person #1 to Group #1:

- Method: POST
- URI: "http://localhost:49432/MyService.svc/Persons(1)/$links/Groups"

With the body as follows:

```
{
    __count: 1,
    results: [{
        uri: "http://localhost:49432/MyService.svc/Groups(1)"
    }]
}
```

However, when I do that, I get the following error:

```
400 Bad Request
"Missing URI element. For link operations, URI element must be specified."
```

I have no idea what URI element is missing. I have provided that in both the request URI and in the payload...

I have also tried several other approaches, but no success so far. Any suggestions?

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want to do more than one link, here's how you do it:

- Method: MERGE
- URI: "http://localhost:49432/MyService.svc/Persons(1)"

Payload should look something like this:

```
{
  Groups: [ { __metadata: { uri:"http://localhost:49432/MyService.svc/Groups(1)" },
            { __metadata: { uri:"http://localhost:49432/MyService.svc/Groups(2)" }
  ]
}
```

Hope this helps.

Thanks
Pratik

Comment: Thank you! I have been doing multiple POSTs from Javascript... Do you know how to remove multiple links at a go?

Comment: There is no way to remove multiple them in a single request, other than trying to batch all the delete requests together.

Comment: How can I rebuild all the links in a single request?

Answer (score 0):

I had it right, except for the body of the request. It should have been much simpler:

```
{ uri: "http://localhost:49432/MyService.svc/Groups(1)" }
```

Sweet!

[EDIT]

Just a note for future reference: it looks like only one link can be created at a time using this method.